# How to add result to a list c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack

I have a piece of code that collects a site's img's href links. I want to add them to a static list so I can compare them later with:

```
var list3 = list2.Except(list1);
```

This is my code :

```
        firstlist = new List<string>();
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.example.com/vasita?sorting=date_desc");
        var Thumbnail = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='searchResultsSmallThumbnail']");
        if (Thumbnail != null)
        {
            var firstlinks = Thumbnail.Descendants("a")
            .Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", "").ToString()).ToList();
            textBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, firstlinks); //shows the results on a textbox
            firstlist.Add(firstlinks);
        }
```

I am new at coding and I do not know how to add to a static list.

I tried `firstlist.Add(firstlinks);` but is giving me an error :

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'string'

Thank you.

Comment: Is `firstLinks` here a `List<string>` or a `List<XmlNode>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add the list of string into the other list of strings.

And to make that you need to use `AddRange` method instead of `Add` (see below):

```
firstlist.AddRange(firstlinks);
```

Hope it will help.